# Is it possible to retrieve the contacts without using Activity class?

Tags: android, lwuit

Is it possible to retrieve the contacts without using Activity class?

I'm using LWUIT for developing android application. I need to retrieve the contacts from android phonebook. How its possible?

Because normally retrieve contacts process achieved in inside of extend Activity class. ( I seen some examples).

In LWUIT, They created own Activity class. 
So i need to achieve some other class not in activity class.

How its possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacts are available from the `android.provider.Contacts` (Android 1.6 and earlier) and `android.provider.ContactsContract` (Android 2.0 and newer) content providers. You do not need an activity to query those content providers using a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: Ok. im using android 2.2. Is it possible add the contacts without using Activity class?

Comment: @bhakki: You do not need an activity to do anything with those content providers. Just use a `ContentResolver`.